# Circular BGP propagation

Tags: routing, bgp, ipv4

This one is a difficult to describe, it's hypothetical because I'm learning about routing and right now I'm focused on BGP.

Let's say my ASN is `65000`, and I announce `192.0.2.0/24`. My peer, AS `65001` updates its routing table with its routes to the network I am announcing, but my ISP(s) routers are not my peers. If AS `65001` (who is receiving my route updates) is peered with my ISP(s), meaning my ISP(s) receive routes from `65001`, does this mean that my ISP(s) will now be able to route traffic to `192.0.2.0/24`, and I have avoided the need to peer directly with my ISP?

If I am horribly wrong on anything, please correct me (or tell me where I can find good documentation).

Comment: Please don't use other people's public IP space in your examples, for example just look at where 1.0.0.0 actually goes these days.

Comment: considering it's against the rules to use RFC1918 space, what would you recommend he use as a hypothetical example?

Comment: @JohnJensen There are reseved blocks for documentation and examples - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737 - 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24, 203.0.113.0/24

Comment: @LapTop006 The same goes for AS numbers, I have edited the post to use private AS numbers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're kind of thinking about it the wrong way, but I'll try to explain.

When you purchase bandwidth from an ISP, this is called **transit** (colloquially in the industry). Assuming you've got yourself some PI space (1.0.0.0/8, for example), you're paying your ISP to get your bits from your network to other networks. So say your AS is 6500, and your ISP is 3356. Bits from any other ASN will also need to **transit** AS3356 to get to you. Let's say that there's another ASN (6501) that buys transit from a different ASN (7224). AS3356 and AS7224 are peers. Now, in order for bits to get from AS6501 to AS6500, the path goes like this:

```
AS6501 -> AS7224 -> AS3356 -> AS6500
```

Now if you set up **peering** (also a colloquial industry term**) with AS6501, this eliminates the need to get bits from you to AS6501 via transit and vice versa, thus reducing your cost, AS6501's operator's cost, and also usually results in reduced loss/latency between your networks. Everybody wins! Now the path looks like this:

```
AS6501 -> AS6500
```

Your original scenario wouldn't work in the real world, because the assumption for AS6501 would be for it to incur a cost to get your bits across it to you from the ISP(s). AS6501 wouldn't be getting benefit by hauling your bits across it to your ISP so you don't have to pay your ISP. What's more likely is AS6501 would charge you to do this, at which point, you might as well just pay your ISP(s) anyway.

** The term **peering** is overloaded. It can be both used to describe a BGP session (e or i variety), as well as the colloquial/political sense, which means you and another network connect to one another and directly exchange traffic (via BGP) for mutual benefit - think ***opposite of transit***. If you're running BGP with your ISP (transit), you're still technically **peering** with your ISP, because it's an **eBGP peering**. To help avoid confusion, it's better to use **peering** to refer to the act of exchanging traffic with another network **at no cost** (note that this isn't always the case) and **BGP session** to refer to the actual technical term for exchanging prefixes via BGP (iBGP or eBGP) with another router, whether a cost is involved or not.

Comment: Thanks, very clear. Just one question: For bits to go from `AS6501 -> AS6500`, wouldn't they have to _physically_ traverse `AS3356` (and `AS7224`)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Not if you're (AS6500) peering with AS6501. The point is that you're avoiding the physical traversing by setting up the peering. Typically these are done with PNI's ("private network interconnection") - a separate physical link from your router to the peer's router, or you and the peer will connect to an IXP's peering fabric and set up eBGP sessions with one another that way.

Comment: I seem to be mis-using the word "peer" then. Maybe my understanding of BGP is limited, but my use of "peer" simply meant that `AS6501` and `AS6500` exchanged routing tables.

Comment: See my edit above where I go more into what *peering* means :-)

Comment: Clearly I've got a lot to learn about the term _peering_ alone. I think I'll just _peer_ with my ISP and make things simpler.

Comment: Your use of "peer" is still correct but with Internet routing at scale (and with the scenario your question is about) it's almost impossible to separate the technical aspect from the political/money aspect, which I do agree can be confusing. Stick with the purely technical for now, and the rest will make sense.

Answer (score 6):

If AS 6501 is willing be a transit AS then they would be able to route to your /8' however it may also depend on whether you obtained your /8 from the said ISP or not.

In terms of good literature then would always highly recommend 'Routing TCP/IP Vol2' by Jeff Doyle & 'Internet Routing Architectures' by Sam Halabi.

Comment: Thanks. But if `6501` routed my `/8`, wouldn't they just be routing to my ISP, who (since they're not peered with me) wouldn't know where to send my traffic (assuming this is before `6501` has sent its table to my ISP)?

If I had obtained the `/8` from my ISP, then they would obviously route it to me (and announce it as well). The point of this situation is to get around the  process of peering with your ISP (maybe they hate you or something, who knows).

Comment: Yeah you correct but i'd assumed you would directly peer (eBGP) with AS6501.

Answer (score 5):

I would just like to add, any Good Actors filter the *unholy crap* out of what they announce to, and accept from peers.  AS6500 would announce only routes to prefixes they own (or that of their customers, who may themselves be an AS.) AS6501 would only allow routes with an origin of 6500 (i.e. `^6500$`) and v.v., and most likely filter on the prefixes themselves *as well*.  A **great deal** of damage can be done by bad actors using ISPs that don't validate what their customers are sending them.

This all gets very complicated rather quickly.  There are various routing registries (IRR's) to help automate the process.

[Note: I've been the "bgp guy" before.  And I've been on the receiving end of someone appropriating our address space -- it was in the 90's so it might've been an actual typo on their part.  Today, it happens on purpose.]

Comment: Never heard networks referred to as "actors" before! :-) What does "v.v." mean?

Comment: @JohnJensen, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VV -- pick the most logical one as I did. ;-)

Comment: And here I was, wondering if it was some AS path filtering acronymn that I'd never heard of. :-\

Comment: There's always the possibility of "announcing the internet" and messing everything up. That's why I'm trying to figure out what kind of security is in place with BGP. Do peers just blindly accept [routing table] updates?

Comment: It's BGP's job to accept all updates, but whether or not those updates are stored in an eBGP speaker's Loc-RIB is a matter of policy and goes back to what @Ricky was talking about re: filtering. In terms of "security" available for BGP, there's TCP MD5 (shouldn't be counted IMO), BGP TTL security, and BGP RPKI/ROA.

Comment: w.r.t. security... there are mechanisms for securing who is allowed to peer, but any "security" on what routes are shared is completely up to the individual peers.  You can blindly accept everything announced to you, but to be blunt, you'd be fool to do so.

Comment: @RickyBeam so essentially, trust nobody and only peer with reputable peers like Level3, nLayer, etc...?

Comment: You can stop at just "_trust nobody_".  People make mistakes; plan for it. (for the record, I've filtered bgp between my own routers.)